# Fivestar rating for anonymous user should redirect to login or register

Tags: rating

When anonymous users tries to rate a node with fivestar rating, they will be asked to either login or register to continue. How to achieve it???

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules) to achieve this.

Check out this [Great tutorial](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/752).

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The question is not 'How to use Rules module?'. please describe how to achieve the user's question using Rules.